How can I select a date period so that I can pull data from the db and download that excel file using Filament 3?
I have a page for reports where I want to download data from three separate database tables from a single button over a certain period.
I currently have it working for three separate buttons, but now I want to be able to pick a date period like from 20 August 1990 to 23 April 2024, and end up getting three files being downloaded for messages, emails and whatsappp messages .
Existing code bellow
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages;

use App\Livewire\BillsReportsStats;
use App\Models\Email;
use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\WhatsappMessage;
use Filament\Actions\Action;
use Filament\Pages\Page;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Exports\EmailReport;
use App\Exports\MessagesReport;
use App\Exports\WhatsappMessagesReport;


class Reports extends Page
{
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-document-text';

    protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.reports';


    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Action::make('Export')
                ->label('Download Emails Report')
                ->action('emailReport')
                ->color('primary')
                ->icon('heroicon-o-cloud-arrow-down'),
                Action::make('messsagesExport')
                ->label('Download Messages Report')
                ->action('messagesReport')
                ->color('primary')
                ->icon('heroicon-o-cloud-arrow-down'),
                Action::make('export')
                ->label('Download Whatsapp Report')
                ->action('whatsappReport')
                ->color('primary')
                ->icon('heroicon-o-cloud-arrow-down'),
        ];
    }

    public function emailReport()
    {
       return Excel::download(new EmailReport(), str(filament()->getTenant()->name)->slug() . '-emails.xlsx');
    }

    public function messagesReport()
    {
        return Excel::download(new MessagesReport(), str(filament()->getTenant()->name)->slug() . '-messages.xlsx');
    }

    public function whatsappReport()
    {
        return Excel::download(new WhatsappMessagesReport(), str(filament()->getTenant()->name)->slug() . '-whatsapp.xlsx');
    }

    //lets add a stats widget to the reports page
    protected function getHeaderWidgets(): array
    {
        return [
            BillsReportsStats::class,
        ];
    }
}

